# Converting Arrow Function that has addEventListener and Parameter Into a Regular ES5 Function

Tags: jquery, arrow-functions, jplist

I'm having some issues converting an arrow Function with addEventListener and parameter to regular ES5 function.

Tried to convert this (works as expected):

```
element.addEventListener('jplist.state', (e) => {
    //do something
});
```

Into this (not working):

```
element.addEventListener("jplist.state", function(e){
    //do something
});
```

But am assuming that I'm missing something (Original arrow function obtained from [JPList filter plugin](https://www.jplist.org/documentation/api/jplist-state-event)).

reason I'm making this change is because IE11 throws error for =>, even with polyfill.

Comment: Try `function(e){
    /*do something*/
}.bind(this)` though this is definitely not an arrow in the code you've linked since that doesn't even use `this`.

Comment: please share complete error message

Comment: Complete error is:
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change in the function's syntax (from arrow function to regular). The issue here was related to my use of the [addEventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) and overlooking the fact that I needed to provide **", true"** for the **useCapture** parameter needed in my case.

**So in the end, I used:**

```
element.addEventListener("jplist.state", function(e){
    //do something
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you cannot polyfill new syntax. It is evaluated by the JavaScript engine in use, and the engine cannot be modified by JavaScript.

Secondly, changing `(e) => {}` to `function (e) {}` makes no difference, so this is not an error with changing the syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your response will...from what it looks like, IE11 doesn't work with the new arrow functions. Thanks for pointing out that the polyfill will not solve it. My main goal in posting is to see if there is a working solution that will work that I can replace with the original above. i have total power to change this.

It works, but my alternative doesn't and with the "jplist.state" event listener that I'm using. It works when I test it with addEventListener("click"... event.

Comment: I figured each of these types of functions were interchangeable (with main difference being syntax)...cant see why custom event isn't being considered (scope or something?).

Comment: Are you using `this` in your event listener by any chance?

Comment: I added it according to what @connexo commented above, but that didn't work...I'm not sure what the reasoning was for that. Not sure of where to add or why. My original change to regular function worked with "click" event...but will not work with the custom "jplist.state".

The update with "this":    
`element.addEventListener("jplist.state", function(e){
    alert('hi');
}.bind(this));`

Comment: @EdgarAlcantara Please view [this JavaScript sample](https://js.do/code/arrow-function-binding) for more information on how arrow functions are bound.

Comment: Hi Will, I do appreciate the help, but don't understand the connection between my issue and what you sent on binding arrow functions. My main issue is that IE11 will no accept arrow functions at all, so in trying to come up with an alternative for the arrow function being used, I tried to convert that into a regular ES5 function. For some reason the alternative I wrote (in my initial question) will not work. Trying to see why. 

I get by pretty well in Js, but am on expert, do I don't understand how binding and this came into the picture.

i just want to convert to function IE can use.

Comment: @EdgarAlcantara You completely missed the point of that sample. Please check it again. It shows how arrow functions are bound.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding. I can see what's going on in the code you provided, but it is not helpful in my case, because I am not trying to do anything to any arrow functions because I can not use an arrow function because Internet Explorer 11 throws a syntax error, because arrow functions are not recognized.

SO, I need to **Completely Replace** the arrow function with a function that **is not** an arrow function. Can you help with that. 

I tried writing the function to replace it (as seen above in my original question), bit it will not work.